# Erro para referencia serviço no Angular

Tags: angular

Bom dia,

Estou com o problema pra referenciar um serviço no angular. Segue erro:

> **ERROR in c:/Projetos/LivroAngular2/src/app/lista-pessoa-vip/lista-pessoa-vip.component.ts
>   (2,10): Module
>   '"c:/Projetos/LivroAngular2/src/app/lista-pessoa-vip/pessoavip-service.service"'
>   has no exported member 'PessoavipService'.**
>
> **ERROR in c:/Projetos/LivroAngular2/src/app/lista-pessoa-vip/lista-pessoa-vip.component.ts
>   (2,10): Module
>   '"c:/Projetos/LivroAngular2/src/app/lista-pessoa-vip/pessoavip-service.service"'
>   has no exported member 'PessoavipService'.**

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá, seria legal vc informar o que vc está fazendo, com qual código, colocar o exemplo do código, uma pergunta somente com o erro não ajuda a galera a ajudar =(

Answer (score 0):

Tem que chamar ele la no ngModules. fazer o import dele la.

Comment: Obrigado Gilmar, solucionei o problema com a sua ajuda.

Comment: Marca como solucionado por favor :)